# .where returns nil exception if user does not enter anything rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to query some data from table based on user for submission.

Its working fine but if I post nothing in the the fields and post my form, it returns me nil exception.

Is there a way we can deal with nil exception, or do I need to change query?

```
question_options = question.question_options.where(id: self.option_id).first
```

Comment: The excption ocours later in your code right? When you try some thing like `question_options.XXX` ?

Comment: Yes, thats right. `question_options.is_correct == true ? self.score = question.points : self.score = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `try`. For example:

```
question_options = question.question_options.where(id: self.option_id).try(:first)
```

The documentation for `try` is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

Comment: undefined method `is_correct' for nil:NilClass
`question_options = question.question_options.where(id: self.option_id).try(:first)
question_options.is_correct == true ? self.score = question.points : self.score = 0`

Comment: Then `try` is still the solution, but you need to use it here: `question_options.try(:is_correct) == true`

Answer (score 0):

For your issue multiple solutions exists. Your query returns `nil` and thats ok because nothing was found. The simplest solution is an `if` statement. `if question_options.nil?` do some thing else. Or you can use an unitialized object (or a NullObject) do work with it `question_option = question.question_options.where(id: self.option_id).first || QuestionOption.new`

The are other possibilites too. It depends on your requirement what way you choose.